# R adding a \ prefix to a character for preparing a latex document

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to add a \ as a prefix to a character vector.
However \ is an escape character in R and I am having trouble doing this.

I tried:

```
group <- c("12357e", "12575e", "197e18", "e18947")
group

group1 <-gsub("e", "\e", group,allowEscapes=T))
```

But this did not work. I also tried:

```
group1 <-gsub("e", "\\e", group)
```

But this also did not work

My intended outcome for group1 is:

```
c("12357\e", "12575\e", "197\e18", "\e18947")
```

The above is just a demo example. I am doing this as I am preparing the text to be used in latex, so I need to put a \ before latex escape characters eg $ needs to be changed to \$ .

Thank you for any help.

Comment: May we ask why you wish to get this output ?

Comment: You need four `\`  i.e. `cat(gsub("e", "\\\\e", group))#12357\e 12575\e 197\e18 \e18947`

Comment: @akrun this gives a double backslash as output

Comment: The print will give only one, it is for escaping

Comment: `z<-gsub("e","\\\\e",group);z;[1] "12357\\e" "12575\\e" "197\\e18" "\\e18947"` even if I agree a `cat(z)` will show only one, it's not the desired  format (but I think the desired format can't be done in R)

Comment: After edit: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406071/r-sweave-latex-escape-variables-to-be-printed-in-latex)

Comment: And [related too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800985/knitr-escape-latex-special-characters-e-g-in-r-code)

Comment: And last if not least: [this one](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/encoded.html) If none of the link above is correct for you, I would love to know why.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai for all the links and insights.

Comment: Did they help you solving your issue ? If yes, consider writing an answer to your question showing how it solve the problem, I'll be happy to upvote it if I think it's the correct way to solve it (probably the last link is the best path IMO)